# I Want to create a notepad application in ionic what storage should i use?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I thought of using localStorage as it will support pc browsers as well as mobile applications

- but i am not sure whether it  will serve my purpose or not.

Comment: localStorage is best fit. as other storage schema may not supported by all browser.

Comment: do you think the text files tht i will save their will persist forever until user uninstall the app ?

Comment: you can not save the file in localStorage. you can only save contents of file. localStorage can get clear if user clears the cache of the app.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is the way to go. It persists information without expiration date, presumably forever, or until the user unistalls the app or erases the application data. Check out [w3schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for some good examples to get started.